# How browser displays a static website contents without any confusion, when two requests are fired from a browser in different tabs

Tags: web, browser, static-pages

I'm a web developer, I just want to know how things work behind the scenes when a request is fired.

Suppose let's assume I've a static website, I requested about us page in one tab, contact us in other tab, both the requests are fired at the same time..

when the requests are fired at the same time, How browser displays the content in respective tabs correctly ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for process id,

In browser each tab have different process id ( you can see that is task manager )

This seperates the send and receiving of the data in each tab...

Comment: Are there any relevant links, explaining how it works ?

Comment: try this [Quora Answer](https://www.quora.com/When-we-open-a-new-tab-in-a-browser-does-it-create-a-new-process-thread-and-why-Which-is-better-and-why)